# How to animate a grease pencil sketch and/or drawn text without using textures in the BGe?

Tags: python, animation, game-engine, grease-pencil

[image: example]

Is there a way of doing this, but as an animation and with the text in the speech balloon being a string entered by the player? I'm guessing it'll involve scripting too, which is okay with me.

Comment: Text is drawn in BGE with text objects like in normal renders so you dont have to use textures...

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't just want existing fonts. I'd like to have this crude, handwritten style for the text, including some variations between instances of each letter (different scrawls of "a" or "b" etc. instead of a standard glyph for each letter). I know there's a way to create a new font, but not whether this particular task is possible. Plus the shape of the speech balloon would need to keep morphing to accommodate the input sting, where I'm again at a loss.

Comment: grease pencil is not supported in the BGE (and never will be). You can indeed render it to texture or a video which can be used within the BGE. unique letters can be the same way, Have one texture for each and every single character. I guess you will quickly notice it is more work than it is worth.